# Error declaring the absence of structure

Tags: c

I am facing problem as my compiler is showing error "request for member x in something not a structure or union" please help as i am confused.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct
{
  float x;
  float y;
} vertex;

int main()
{
  int *p, T, N, i, j;
  printf("enter the number of inputs required\n");
  scanf("%d", &T);

  printf("enter the number of polygons\n");
  scanf("%d\n", &N);
  p = (int *) malloc(N*sizeof(int));
  for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    printf("enter the number of vertices of the %dth polygon\n");
    scanf("%d", p + i);
  }

  vertex *q[N];

  for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    q[i] = (vertex *) malloc(*(p + i) * sizeof(vertex));
    for(j = 0; j < *(p + i); j++)
    {
      printf("enter the x coordinate\n");
      scanf("%f", &(*(q[i]+j).x)); /*here the error is shown*/
      printf("enter the y coordinate\n");
      scanf("%f", &(*(q[i]+j).y));
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you sure you want to say *(q[i]+j).x) and not *(q[i+j]).x) ?

Comment: What system and compiler do You use?

Comment: use `&q[i][j].x` and `&q[i][j].y`

Comment: Don't hesitate to use spaces in your code.  I have extras if you need some.

Comment: @Andre yes ! what is mentioned is correct ,i'm using pointers

Comment: Here are some further problems in your code: There is a trailing white-space character at the end of the `scanf`, which could be a problem. The `"%d"` in the third `printf` lacks a corresponding decimal, which also is bad.

Comment: BLUEPIXY thanks that worked but whats the wrong in my code would you please clarify

Comment: Well the reason is that '.' has higher priority in precedence table over '*' ...thanks a lot everyone

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%f",&(*(q[i]+j).x));
```

has lots of problems. Let's take them inside out:

```
q[i]
```

is a `vertex *`, because `q` is an array of `vertex *`. That's fine.

```
q[i] + j
```

is the address of the `j`th vertex pointer after q in memory. If the pointer in `q[i]` was itself a member of an array, this might be OK. In fact you are assigning a malloc'd block to `q[i]`. Note, however, that since a pointer plus an int makes a pointer, that you're not getting a `vertex`, but another `vertex *`.

```
(q[i] + j).x
```

Is invalid, because `x` is a member of `vertex`, and we don't have one of those. You need

```
(q[i] + j)->x
```

or

```
(*(q[i] + j)).x
```

or

```
q[i][j].x
```

(remember that `a[i]` means `*(a+i)`).

Then you can finally take the address of that for scanf.

Comment: I think you missed a closing parenthesis in `(*(q[i] + j).x` .

Comment: Adding this priority table for reference: http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html The member access operator dot has higher priority than the dereferencing asterisk.

Comment: Right.  In the end, although there are several problems, the actual error the OP asked about boils down to the priority of the dereferencing operator (unary `*`) *vs* that of the member access operator (`.`).

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks a lot sir, that clarified my confusion , dot has higher priority than *.  :)